# 64 Bit Windows 8.1 Failure to reinstall Java JDK and JRE

Tags: windows-8.1, java, jdk, jre

Attempting to update to jre-7u67 from 65 did not appear to work. On reattempting, installation failed with a “Access is denied” message. JDK was still there but I followed recommendations to remove all Java applications and references.  Then both new or old JREs and JDKs failed with the same message.  A log entry for JDK was “JDK installation failed.  Return Code: 1603, ErrorCode: 0 updating component registration”. Can anyone help?

Comment: Read the following and try the solution http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834484

Comment: That is for Windows XP and 2000. I tried the end permission changes but that was rejected by Win 8.1. I haven’t found the same information yet for Win 8.1.

Comment: Which one of those conditions applies to your system?

Comment: None, tried on main HD Windows C partition and D partition that are not encrypted. SYSTEM permissions appear to be correct. I have just tried another suggestion which is installing from a copy in Users AppData, where there is a jre .msi file and a Data1.cab file. This failed, but I followed the suggestion to Trouble shoot compatibility of the .msi file. This ended up indicating that the file is incompatible - Googling for this now.

Comment: After trying various suggested solutions over the last week, I used the end of the road procedure to refresh the PC. At least I could check the USB stick recovery drive that I produced. Then Java JRE installed successfully. Now, I have to reinstall a few other things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30151035/435706 maybe

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, in the Russian version Windows 8.1.
After join to the domain, jre7u55, jre7u60, jre8, jre8u5 not installed.

There is a temporary solution:
1. Install English Lang Pack
2. Apply English for Display language and Copy settings to Welcome screen and system accounts
3. Return the old language, and copy settings to New user accounts
4. jre7u55, jre7u60, jre8, jre8u5  install successfully.

Original text:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3578474

Answer (score 0):

Download and run the Microsoft Program Install and Uninstall Fixit Tool here: http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en

Once prompted to select a program to remove, select your JDK/JRE you're trying to reinstall. Doing so will uninstall them. Then once that is completed, you may proceed to installing the JDK/JRE.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following things.

1. Remove the Java related environment variables like JAVA_HOME.
2. Delete all the folders inside Java folder from Program Files, Program Files (x86).
3. Download offline installer for 64 bit Windows 8.1.
4. Restart the machine.
5. Install java.